# How do I get the screw modifier to go around the Y axis for a 2d Trace

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, screw-modifier

I want to recreate a chess piece (Bishop) by wrapping a side trace around the y axis. However, when I use the screw modifier, it decides the y axis isn't good enough and [does this to me](https://imgur.com/T1zkvsD).

[image]

This isn't just an issue with my complicated line either, it seems that all bezier curves have this problem: here's a [example](https://imgur.com/TBTeZlR) of the what I'm talking about.

[image]

This shape, rather than pivoting along the y axis, pivots along a slightly tilted axis of its own. How do I fix this? Changing the center of origin doesn't help.

TL;DR

Is there any simple way to tell blender to screw a trace around an axis ignoring an object's origin?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you rotated the object used by Screw modifier in Object mode, so apply its rotation with Ctrl+A.

Answer (score 2):

The screw modifier by default uses the Z axis, you can change this in the modifier options.

If the revolution axis doesn't correspond to the world Y axis its because your object is rotated in *Object Mode*.

Check your objects rotation in the *3D View > Properties Shelf > Rotation* (<kbd>N</kbd> Key)
[image]