How to extrude in a circle?
I am trying to import a .svg shape and extrude/rotate it to make a round object.
What I have now:

A SVG file
I want to make it an object like this:

Until it looks like this with the faces filled out:

I have used arrays in the past, but when I try to use an array for this nothing changes when I offset it on the Z axis.
I am also getting an error message saying "The offset is too small, we cannot generate the amount of geometry it would require". My object seemed really small when I imported it, I designed it in Illustrator an imported it and it should be about 68mm wide in total).


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139864/rotate-a-2d-cross-section-to-make-a-3d-object/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78961/how-do-i-get-the-screw-modifier-to-go-around-the-y-axis-for-a-2d-trace/78966#78966
