# How to make a smooth object look less 'lumpy'

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I'm editing an object. Here's how it looks when editing:

[image]

and here's how it looks when rendered, with a subdivision surface modifier:

[image]

That outer surface just doesn't look as smooth as I'd like. You can sort of see where edges of the model are - some parts of it are slightly less curved than others, which gives it a slightly lumpy appearance. I'd like it to be a completely smooth, parabola-like surface instead.

I realise that what I mean might not be clear from the image above, so here's an exaggerated picture of how the shape currently looks to me, compared to what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

I don't think the issue has to do with the coarseness of the final mesh, or with the shading, but rather, it's to do with how my very coarse model is being interpolated by the subdivision modifier, and the lack of control I'm able to exert over that process.

I can fix the shape by adding loop cuts and then fine-tuning their positions, but that takes a lot of manual fiddling, and it's rather time consuming because in this case the lumpiness can't really be seen without doing a full render. Because of this, I'm wondering if there's something I can do that will take my existing model and render it in a more smoothed-out way.

I am a beginner and may well be unaware of an obvious way to do this.

I tried changing the crease value of the edges that make up the curve to -1, but that didn't appreciably change the shape, and also introduced some Mach banding, for some reason. (I removed the image of this failed attempt, because I realised it was in danger of confusing the issue, since that image contains a different kind of non-smoothness than the one I'm asking about. Please don't edit that image back in again. If anyone wants to see it, it's in the edit history.)

Comment: you need more geometry in the mesh (or more subdivisions in the modifier) to get smoother curves. Or you can try modeling all of it with curves. Can you share your model?

Comment: I am not an expert or anything but the first thing I would ask is did you recalculate normal's? a face with a flipped normal can pull stuff out of shape. your mesh would be in edit mode select all in the mesh drop-down >  normal's > recalculate outside

Comment: +1 on @susu comment. You need a bit more topology to help smooth those transitions. Another great way to model cylindrical type objects is with curves. Lots of tutorials on that.

Comment: Try enabling autosmooth and then changing shading type to smooth

Comment: How much subdivisions do you have ? I tried making the it with the same geometry that you have except the fact that I have 32 vertecies for my cylinder .i got and quite satisfying result with 3 subdivisions and with auto smooth enabled ...

Comment: Remember that sub-surf will only divide your geometry it wont smooth out every thing unnecessarily. So adding loopcuts and creating that perfect curve will give you the best result I guess. I was just using a custom glass shader . I think the material also matters in such cases.

Comment: General response to comments: I understand that you need more geometry to make a better curve - that much is clear. The question then is whether that geometry can be generated automatically. What I want to avoid is manually fiddling with each individual loop cut. The lumpiness can only really be seen when doing a full render, so that's very time-consuming. I'd happily work out an equation for the radius as a function of x, if there's a way that could be entered somewhere.

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 by auto smooth do you mean Add Modifier -> Deform -> Smooth or something else? I tried that (after the subdivision modifier) but it had no noticeable effect.

Comment: I think I have 3 subdivisions in the render I posted, but increasing it doesn't have much effect. I believe the issue is not to do with the final mesh being too coarse, but to do with how it's interpolating the few data points I've given it.

Comment: @AD same question as the one I asked Nxdhin above: does "autosmooth" mean a smooth modifier or something else?

Comment: Another general response: I had no idea modelling with curves was even an option. (I've only really done the donut tutorial.) I'll look into that.

Comment: You can turn on autosmooth in object data properties panel -> Normals and enable autosmooth to smoothen out your shading -https://imgur.com/a/O27yN29

Comment: No need of modelling with a curve you can get good results with the cylinder itself. I hope smooth shading is enable cuz its necessary to toggle on auto smooth

Comment: Geometry cannot be created automatically as far as i know

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 I've tried turning on autosmooth, but it has no visible effect in this case. I don't think this is an issue with the shading at all - see my edit to the question

Comment: As I told I think the materials matter . The material may be exaggerating the irregularities. Sharing your file may prove helpful.(Since my glass shader doest have that..)

Comment: Autosmooth is a setting under the object properties panel just enable that and then in the 3d veiwport select the object and then select smooth shading by right-clickin.

Comment: I think modeling with a curve and use the Screw modifier on it, [as seen in the answer to this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78961/how-do-i-get-the-screw-modifier-to-go-around-the-y-axis-for-a-2d-trace), could really simplify things. You would only need to manipulate a couple (possibly literally) of vertices.

Comment: @Fjoersteller that sounds like the right way to do it. I wasn't aware that kind of thing was possible before the comments to this question. I'll have a go at it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a self-answer, based on information from the comments. There is a very nice trick to this, which is to model using Bézier curves instead of just relying on the subdivision surface modifier.

The basic procedure is to do shift-A -> Curve -> Bezier. Then in properties there's a curve panel where you can turn it into 2D, which makes editing easier. Then you can add a 'screw' modifier, followed by subdivision surface and, in my case, solidify.

Here's how the object looks modelled with curves:
[image]

The weird lumpiness has gone, and in addition, editing is much quicker and more painless, and it's easier to be accurate.

It looks like this when editing. I only have to change a couple of control points to change the slope of the curve - the geometry is generated automatically.

[image]

[image]